# MVVM Tabs: Focus new tab

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I can add & remove tabs similar to the famous [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). Basically a `ObservableCollection<TabViewModels>`. And I add tabs like `_tabs.Add(new TabViewModel())` but the newest tab is not focused. I want to focus it. How do I do it?

**1 way to do it**

since i have a view source for my observable collection, I can do the below... another option will be @vorrtex method

```
public void OnTabsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count > 0)
        foreach (TabViewModel tab in e.NewItems)
        {
            tab.CloseRequested += OnCloseRequested;
            _tabsViewSource.MoveCurrentTo(tab);
        }
    if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count > 0)
        foreach (TabViewModel tab in e.OldItems)
            tab.CloseRequested -= OnCloseRequested;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use SelectedItem:

```
    public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> Pages { get; set; }

    private TabViewModel currentPage;

    public TabViewModel CurrentPage
    {
        get { return currentPage; }
        set
        {
            currentPage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPage");
        }
    }

    public void AddPage()
    {
        var page = new TabViewModel();
        this.Pages.Add(page);
        this.CurrentPage = page;
    }
```

XAML:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPage, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: I also found another way to do it, in my update since i am using `CollectionViewSource`. That way, I won't need yet another property

Comment: This worked great, MVVM is so lovely in situations like this. BTW, I used SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath.